# How to use OR operator with SUBSTR in Oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

I would like to select values of a substring with an OR operator, but I am receiving `ORA-00920: invalid relational operator`

I am using Oracle CX and Python to execute this query.  How should this be written to successfully execute `SUBSTR(b.JOBID,11,11) OR Where SUBSTR(b.JOBID,10,10)`?

I am unable to add the complete SQL.

Comment: Please post the complete SQL.

Comment: It's `WHERE <conditon> OR <codintion>`

Comment: Can you describe the problem in plain English though? It is not at all clear why you would compare "something" either to a 10-character substring starting at position 10 or an 11-character string starting at position 11. (Specifically, why the comparison would be to substrings of different length.) Are you 100% sure you are using `SUBSTR( , , )` correctly to begin with - never mind using two of them, separated by `OR`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
Where SUBSTR(b.JOBID,11,11) = a.MEMBERCODE OR 
        SUBSTR(b.JOBID,10,10) = a.MEMBERCODE
```

Comment: `Where SUBSTR(b.JOBID,11,11) OR SUBSTR(b.JOBID,10,10) = a.MEMBERCODE` does not work.

Comment: Where SUBSTR(b.JOBID,11,11) = a.MEMBERCODE OR SUBSTR(b.JOBID,10,10) = a.MEMBERCODE

Comment: if you change your answer I will mark it correct!  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You'll have do the each comparison separately and then, `OR` them together

```
Where SUBSTR(b.JOBID,11,11) = a.MEMBERCODE OR SUBSTR(b.JOBID,10,10) = a.MEMBERCODE
```